# ImperativeExpression for ToolItems

Tags: eclipse, e4

I add the same ImperativeExpression to DirectToolItem and DirectMenuItem, but my `@Evaluate` method in class for expression was called only for DirectMenuItem. So I can't manage the visibility of DirectToolItem by ImperativeExpression. This is bug or I need to send some event to update visibility? Something like `UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the visible-when expression for a tool item does not currently work at all. Eclipse bug [494663](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494663) describes the problem.